# unable to set z-index, overflow-y, etc. in coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, infowindow, gmaps4rails

In my Rails app, I was trying to customize `infobox` for Gmaps assisting with `gmaps4rails` gem. While I was defining some css attributes like `z-index`, `overflow-y` to customize it, I've faced error like below:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError at /
SyntaxError: [stdin]:22:15: unexpected -
  (in ../app/assets/javascripts/infobox.js.coffee)
```

Here's the file seems to be responsible for the error:

`../app/assets/javascripts/infobox.js.coffee`:

```
# omitted
infobox: (boxText)->
  content: boxText
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-70, -110)
  boxStyle: {
    background: '#fefefe',
    width: '250px',
    height: '80px',
    border: "1px solid black",
    padding: "5px 10px",
    overflow-y: "hidden",
    z-index: 54
  }
```

How can I define these attributes for infobox?

Comment: have you tried `'overflow-y': 'hidden'` and `'z-index': 54`? I don't think that CoffeeScript likes these dashes `-` in the code

Comment: @MrYoshiji I've already tried with them.

Comment: it does work for me in my local env AND for js to coffee translator (http://coffeescript.org/#try:infobox%3A%20(boxText)-%3E%0A%20%20content%3A%20boxText%0A%20%20pixelOffset%3A%20new%20google.maps.Size(-70%2C%20-110)%0A%20%20boxStyle%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20background%3A%20'%23fefefe'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20'250px'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%20'80px'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20border%3A%20%221px%20solid%20black%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20padding%3A%20%225px%2010px%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'overflow-y'%3A%20%22hidden%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22z-index%22%3A%2054%0A%20%20%7D)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Oops, I've tried with double-quotation instead of single one. Wonder why has it been different in both situations?

Comment: I have no idea why it would work with double quote (or single) and not work with the other ... That is odd!

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes from JavaScript, and [the CoffeeScript project doesn't want to fiddle with it](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/433) (justifiably, as it introduces some consistency problems). In JavaScript you can't use dashes in property names unless they're in strings; As MrYoshiji says, quoting them will make your JS work fine:

```
infobox: (boxText)->
  content: boxText
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-70, -110)
  boxStyle: {
    background: '#fefefe',
    width: '250px',
    height: '80px',
    border: "1px solid black",
    padding: "5px 10px",
    'overflow-y': "hidden",
    "z-index": 54
  }
```

You should be able to use either quote style without problems.

Comment: Are you trying to steal my reputation, @AlexP? :-P And you dare copy-paste the code I produced on jsFiddle ?!

Comment: I'm sorry if I stepped on your toes - I wasn't trying to steal anything. I saw the question had no official answers so wanted to make sure that it had one, to help other people who landed here from Google. I did try to add some links to other resources, and spent some time in the JS specs but didn't find anything that was clear to link to re: character limits. I also tried to give credit, and I didn't copy and paste your code. I did keep the idea of demonstrating the use of both quote styles; I thought it was useful information. Sorry again.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your input in this case. If you do this next time (answer an question answered by the comment), name the original finder of the solution, at least.

Comment: I did include your name in my original answer; was that not prominent enough?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't get the StackOverflow's notice and I should have double-checked that. I am sorry for this last reproach

Answer (score 1):

Using quotes makes it work: [Coffescript to Javascript permalink](http://coffeescript.org/#try:infobox%3A%20(boxText)-%3E%0A%20%20content%3A%20boxText%0A%20%20pixelOffset%3A%20new%20google.maps.Size(-70%2C%20-110)%0A%20%20boxStyle%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20background%3A%20'%23fefefe'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20'250px'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%20'80px'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20border%3A%20%221px%20solid%20black%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20padding%3A%20%225px%2010px%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'overflow-y'%3A%20%22hidden%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22z-index%22%3A%2054%0A%20%20%7D)

The final code for you would be:

```
infobox: (boxText)->
  content: boxText
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-70, -110)
  boxStyle: {
    background: '#fefefe',
    width: '250px',
    height: '80px',
    border: "1px solid black",
    padding: "5px 10px",
    "overflow-y": "hidden",
    "z-index": 54
  }
```